# My code for rotating arrays gives error for large array size

Tags: c++, arrays

**Problem**: I was trying to solve this problem from geeksforgeeks on array rotation. The code seems to be working fine for small array size but for large array size it displays some garbage values and then stops working.

The question is on this link: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/rotate-and-delete/0

and my code is:

```
# include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void rotate_clockwise(int *arr, int size)
{
    int temp = *(arr + size -1);
    for(int i = 0;i < size;++i )
    {
        *(arr +(size -1) - i) = *(arr + (size-1) -(i+1));//*(arr +(size -1)) 
    }
    *arr = temp;
}

void initialize_array(int *arr,int size)
{

   for(int  i= 0; i < size; ++i)
   {
        cin>>*(arr +i);
   }


}

void print_array(int *arr,int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< size; i++)
    {
        cout<<*(arr + i)<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void remove_ith_fend(int i, int *arr, int *ptr_size)
{   
    int size = *ptr_size;

    int *last = (arr + size -1);

    i = i-1;

    if(i < size)
    {
        for(int j =0 ;j<size;j++)
        {
            *(last - i + j) = *(last -i + j+1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j = 0;j<size;++j)
        {
            *(arr + j) = *(arr + j +1);
        }
    }
    --size;
    *ptr_size = size;
    }

int main()
{
    int size;

    cout<<"Enter size of array: ";

    cin>>size;
    int *ptr_size;
    ptr_size = &size;

    int arr[size];

    initialize_array(arr, size);

    print_array(arr, size);

    for(int i =1;size!=1;++i)
    {
        cout<<"rotating"<<endl;

        rotate_clockwise(arr,size);

        print_array(arr,size);

        remove_ith_fend(i, arr, ptr_size);

        cout<<"removing "<<i<<"th element from the end"<<endl;

        print_array(arr,size);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was only trying this out so I don't take input for test cases which they are giving in the question.
Sorry I have not commented the code but I was in the process of solving this and 
was going to do it later after getting the solution right.

Here is the error I was getting when I entered the array size: 54

```
Enter size of array: 54
4741824 0 -1 0 4744768 0 4503683 0 1 0 4745728 0 8 0 4751362 0 4744784 0 
7339432 0 7339436 0 1 0 0 0 -1 0 4741824 0 -1 0 4741824 0 10 0 4254288 
16777216 0 54 8390488 0 224 0 -1 0 4200452 0 0 0 0 0 8 0
rotating
0 4741824 0 -1 0 4744768 0 4503683 0 1 0 4745728 0 8 0 4751362 0 4744784 0 
7339432 0 7339436 0 1 0 0 0 -1 0 4741824 0 -1 0 4741824 0 10 0 4254288 
16777216 0 54 8390488 0 224 0 -1 0 4200452 0 0 0 0 0 8
removing 1th element from the end
```

It didn't asked for any input and just exited after printing this thing above.
Also please point out some issues that I have with the way code is written as I am new to programming and like to learn the better way of writing.

I just debugged the code using visual studio and it showed this message

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0000000000401632 in second.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
violation reading location 0x0000000000000000. occurred
```

name of the file is second.

also the correct output should look like this:

```
Enter size of array: 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
rotating
6 1 2 3 4 5
removing 1th element from the end
6 1 2 3 4
rotating
4 6 1 2 3
removing 2th element from the end
4 6 1 3
rotating
3 4 6 1
removing 3th element from the end
3 6 1
rotating
1 3 6
removing 4th element from the end
3 6
rotating
6 3
removing 5th element from the end
3
```

Did some more testing and found that it works for array size 8 and 10 but not for 7 and 9 and stops working for values greater than 10.

Comment: How do you not get an error for not using a fixed value, or `const int` to define array size?

Comment: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal VLA's are a compiler extension, not C++ standard tho.

Comment: I used powershell to compile and it didn't give any warning, Is it wrong to use fixed  value to define array size  using int?? I seriously don't know.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is a mess to read and understand - use indexing instead.

Comment: When `i` is `size - 1`, `(size-1)-(i+1)` is `-1`, so your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Nothing to do with your question but why do you write `*(arr + i)` instead of `arr[i]`? It makes your code hard to read.

Comment: yeah I did not get how pointers worked.so, I thought maybe I will try and learn by using them.

Comment: @YashSharma *I just debugged the code using visual studio* -- This code could never had compiled with this: `int arr[size];`

Comment: @YashSharma You also should be using `std::vector` if you want to resize.   Arrays cannot be resized by definition, so what you're doing is hacking a fake resize instead of actually resizing.  In addition `std::vector<int> arr(size);` replaces the syntax mentioned in the earlier comment, where Visual C++ (and standard C++) does not allow variable-length arrays.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks mate, I was having problem understanding why vectors were used instead of arrays in all the solutions. I will write the code using vectors now. Also I don't get what is wrong with using 'arr[size]' .

Comment: @YashSharma *Also I don't get what is wrong with using 'arr[size]'* -- It's just plain wrong.  Pretend it doesn't exist, it is fake C++.  The problem is that new programmers get fooled into thinking it is ok because the compiler defaults into allowing such syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem

```
void initialize_array(int *arr,int size)
{
   for(int  i ; i < size; ++i)
   {
        cin>>*(arr +i);
   }
}
```

should be

```
void initialize_array(int *arr,int size)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
   {
        cin>>*(arr +i);
   }
}
```

Your compiler should have wanred you about the uninitialised variable. Pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: I just did the correction but its still not working, and I used powershell to compile but didn't get a warning earlier.

Comment: I will also edit the question and initialize 'i' because I did that in my code

Comment: @YashSharma normally it isnt good to edit the question to incorporate fixes from answers (it makes the answer pointless). However, if the actual problem really persists and if this fix really does not change the behaviour/output of your code then it is fine imho. Just note that johns effort to write this answer is then kinda wasted

Comment: sorry but the problem still persisits, so that's why edited but  won't do it again in the future.